# Python pandas apply date_range onto two columns

Tags: python, date, pandas, range

My dataframe looks like this:

```
df[['reported_date', 'current_date']].head()
    reported_date        current_date
0   2016-01-15 13:58:21  2016-01-18 00:00:00
1   2016-01-14 10:51:24  2016-01-18 00:00:00
2   2016-01-15 15:17:35  2016-01-18 00:00:00
3   2016-01-17 17:07:10  2016-01-18 00:00:00
4   2016-01-17 17:08:23  2016-01-18 00:00:00
```

I can apply date subtraction directly like:

```
df[['reported_date', 'current_date']].head().apply(lambda x: x[1]-x[0], axis=1)
```

but when I tried to apply date_range to get the interval between the days I got the following error

```
df[['reported_date', 'current_date']].head().apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(x[0], x[1], freq='B'), axis=1)

"ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index"
```

So what's the right way to apply `date_range()` to two columns of `datetime` ?

Thank you in advance.

jian

Comment: the number of items generated by the date_range must equal the length of the dataframe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pd.date_range` doesn't return an interval. It returns a series (`DateTimeIndex` really) of *all* datetime objects between start and end. 
Since start is `reported_date` here and is variable, while the end is `current_date` and is fixed, you get series of different lengths, which obviously don't fit nicely into a single (new) column.

The subtraction you use before gives you the interval between the dates. So there is no reason to use `pd.date_range`: `x[1] - x[0]` does exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks, Evert, it's the length of the returned DateTimeIndex that I want.